# Use mid and inner join SQL query in VBA excel

Tags: sql, vba, excel

Please find the below table where i want to execute mid and inner join SQL query.

table 1:-

[image]

table 2:-

[image]

Please find my below syntax and the respective error's which i am facing on the same.

**1st sql query syntax**

```
sql_string = "SELECT [Sheet1$].[Sr], [Sheet2$].[Value], [Name] FROM" & _
" [Sheet2$] INNER JOIN [Sheet1$] ON" & _
" [Sheet1$].[Sr]=(SELECT mid([Sheet2$].[Name], INSTR([Sheet2$].[Name],""#""), len([Sheet2$].[Name])) FROM [Sheet2$]);"
```

error on above code.

[image]

**2nd sql query syntax**

```
sql_string = "SELECT [Sheet1$].[Sr], [Sheet2$].[Value], [Name] FROM " & _
"(SELECT mid([Sheet2$].[Name], INSTR([Sheet2$].[Name],""#""), len([Sheet2$].[Name]))KeyValue FROM [Sheet2$]) as [Sheet2$]" & _
" [Sheet2$] INNER JOIN [Sheet1$] ON [Sheet1$].[Sr]=[Sheet2$].KeyValue;"
```

error on above code.

[image]

Please guide me on the same.

Please find the expected output.

[image]

Comment: What do you want to fetch exactly?

Comment: @PankajJaju Sir, In **table2 column Sr** after **#** there are some number's which is similar to **table1 column Sr** number's.I want to do inner join as per that particular number.

Comment: Still not clear ... can you paste the expected outcome?

Comment: @PankajJaju Sir, Updated the same in question.. please refer my 1st comment and updated required output...

Comment: Have you checked you have the right number of parentheses (opening and closing) for correct syntax?

Comment: @QHarr Sir, yes all the brackets are open and close with the respective syntax.. please guide...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below query

```
Select [Sheet1$].[Sr], [Sheet2$].[Name], [Sheet2$].[Value] From [Sheet1$] Inner Join [Sheet2$] On CInt([Sheet1$].[Sr]) = CInt(Mid([Sheet2$].[Name],InStr(1,[Sheet2$].[Name],""#"")+1))
```

**Sample Code**

```
Dim objCN, objRS

Set objCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRS = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

On Error Resume Next
objCN.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\Book1.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';"
objRS.Open "Select [Sheet1$].[Sr], [Sheet2$].[Name], [Sheet2$].[Value] From [Sheet1$] Inner Join [Sheet2$] On CInt([Sheet1$].[Sr]) = CInt(Mid([Sheet2$].[Name],InStr(1,[Sheet2$].[Name],""#"")+1))", objCN, 3, 1, 1

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
Else
    On Error GoTo 0
    Sheet3.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset objRS
End If

objRS.Close: Set objRS = Nothing: Set objCN = Nothing
```

Comment: your given syntax is correct, but now further i am facing error i.e. **Data type mismatch in criteria expression.**  in **Sheet3.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset objRS** step.please help thanks in advance..

Comment: I tested the code based on your sample data and it works for me. Can you try pasting it in a new sheet and see if it works? May be some sort of formatting in Sheet3 is causing an issue

Comment: i tried in another sheet also now i am facing error that is **invalid use of null** ,please if possible share your sheet where you tried and tested the above query. mail id- sagarsawant36@yahoo.in

Comment: 1- Are you using the exact same data set that you pasted in your question? 2- Have you debugged individual fields to confirm the data is correct? 3- Try with a new workbook and see if you have the same issue

Comment: **1-** yes the data is as it is same.. **2-**  yes step by step i have debugged and facing **invalid use of null** error in **Sheet3.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset objRS** step **3-** Yes I have tried with new workbook Also...Dear Sir if possible, please you share me the workbook where you tried so that minor error will be identified...

Comment: Instead of pasting using CopyFromRecordset ... try printing each row one by one and check where exactly is the error